# ORA-00904: "FNAME": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table MYTAB with the following columns name, contact and grade. Now I run the following commands

```
alter table MYTAB rename column "name" to "fname";
alter table MYTAB add lname varchar(10);
update MYTAB set lname='hay'where fname='rick'
```

After running the last command i got the following error

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "FNAME": invalid identifier``

Comment: Why do you sometimes delimit the column names, and sometimes not? (`"fname"` and `fname`.) `"fname"` is in lower case, while fname is converted to upper case `FNAME`...

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that you named a column literal "fname" and not fname.  [The oracle syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljrenamecolumnstatement.html) would seem to suggest you don't need quotation marks around new column name. Have you checked the table after the first column rename?

Comment: pretty sure there is a probleme with `"`. What's the name of your column in your db ?

Comment: My tables look like this

fname             MOB GR LNAME
---------- ---------- -- ----------
rick           123123 A
flair          123456 b
new            123456 c
old            123456 c
other          123456 b
something      123456 a
desktop        123456 b
text           123456 d

Comment: `"fname"` is a different name then `fname`. Once you start using those dreaded double quotes you have to **always** use them. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Answer (score 1):

The delimited identifier `"fname"` is in lower case, but `fname` is converted to upper case `FNAME`.

Be consistent, **either** always use delimited identifiers (always `"fname"`), **or** always use regular identifiers (always `fname`, without the double quotes.)

Personally I'd chose regular identifiers, simply do `fname`.

Comment: can you please explain briefly

Comment: @Upasana . . . If you use double quotes when you define the column, use double quotes when you refer to it.  However, I would recommend defining all identifiers with no double quotes.